# Combining two functions in one

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, function

How can I combine functions **mark_block** and **mark_cell** into single function?

```
import numpy as np

class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cells = np.zeros((3, 3, 3, 3))
        self.block = np.zeros((3, 3))

    def mark_block(self, main_row, main_col, player):
        self.block[main_row][main_col] = player

    def mark_cell(self, main_row, main_col, row, col, player):
        self.cells[main_row][main_col][row][col] = player
```

EDIT: Would it also be possible to do it without if statement?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "combining into a single"?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès function that can either do mark_cell or mark_block.

Comment: Why are you trying to combine them AND not use an IF statement? What precisely do you wish to achieve? This strikes me as an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @EdwardHenryBrenner A single function that makes both the settings? Or a single function that either depending on arguments that makes one of the settings?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cells = np.zeros((3, 3, 3, 3))
        self.block = np.zeros((3, 3))

    def mark(self, main_row, main_col, player, row=None, col=None):
        if row is None and col is None:
            self.block[main_row][main_col] = player
        else:
            self.cells[main_row][main_col][row][col] = player
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to do it without if statement?

Comment: I would suggest that you also add type hint, function docs and error detection if you don't want to just fail...

Comment: @EdwardHenryBrenner Why??? What precisely are you trying to achieve that separate methods doesn't achieve?